# python numpy (v1.15.0) fails to fit parabola

Tags: python, numpy, polynomial-approximations

I'm having trouble understanding why is numpy having such a hard time fitting parabola to this data ?

```
def make_poly(x, coefs):
    # generate a polynomial from an array of coefficients
    f = numpy.zeros(len(x))
    for i in range(len(coefs)):
        f = f + coefs[-1-i]*x**i
    return(f)


xx = [1443.56, 1443.56, 1450.83, 1447.59, 1454.9, 1434.77, 1423.74, 1426.87, 1438.75, 1447.59, 1454.9, 1444.36, 1454.9, 1426.09, 1454.08, 1453.27, 1447.59, 1449.2, 1451.64, 1454.08, 1454.08, 1454.9, 1454.9, 1455.71, 1452.45, 1450.01, 1453.27, 1430.81, 1454.9, 1448.39, 1432.39, 1452.45, 1445.16, 1431.6, 1447.59, 1447.59, 1425.3, 1443.56, 1453.27, 1424.52, 1429.23, 1421.4, 1454.08, 1445.97, 1427.66, 1429.23, 1433.18, 1430.81, 1440.35,1429.23]

yy = [120.15, 120.15, 123.09, 122.07, 123.52, 116.35, 104.75, 108.34, 119.13, 122.07, 124.27, 120.29, 124.27, 106.6, 124.27, 124.13, 122.07, 122.2,  122.34, 123.37, 124.27, 124.27, 124.27, 124.41, 122.34, 122.2,  123.24, 111.95, 124.27, 121.31, 113.71, 123.24, 121.18, 113.71, 121.31, 122.07, 106.6,  121.04, 124.13, 105.61, 110.96, 100.31, 123.37, 121.18, 109.21, 111.83, 114.58, 112.83, 118.38, 110.96]

fit_result = numpy.polyfit(x=xx, y=yy, deg=2, full=True)
newX = numpy.linspace(1420, 1460, 100)
pyplot.scatter(xx, yy)
pyplot.plot(newX, make_poly(newX, fit_result[0]), 'g', linewidth =.5)
pyplot.show()
```

Running this also throws the message:

```
Python(35100,0x7fff9cda3380) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=18446744072151506944) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
init_dgelsd failed init
```

I am running this on OS High Sierra, Python 3.7.0, numpy 1.15.0 (installed using homebrew).

Comment: Your code works, this is the output I get on my machine https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ2zo.png

Comment: Your output is what is expected.
 After upgrading numpy from 1.15.0 to 1.15.1 it worked on my machine also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code provided in the sample works well.
So, I suppose the problem is laying in the packages versions state.
Likely to fix the error you have to ensure that wheel, setuptools and pip + the packages you are using is up to date. Use the commands below for that:

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
pip install -I numpy matplotlib # + Other packages.
```

After completing installation retry. If the error persist, please extend question with the versions of the python and packages you are using ( so it shall became reproducible).

**Update:**

The answer above has fixed the problem, especially the upgrading numpy from the `1.15.0` to `1.15.1`

Comment: @DusanKojic thanks for letting me know :) Do you want me to include that into answer ?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I moved the comment below the post for better visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for `init_dgelsd` on Google turns up this bug report: [py-numpy: numpy.polyfit broken with +gfortran variant on High Sierra](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/56954).

You can run

```
import numpy
numpy.test('full')
```

... to run NumPy's built-in test suite and see if it returns any problems.

Mojca Miklavec [suggests](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/56954#comment:22):

> Apparently either
>
> `sudo port install py37-numpy +gcc7`
>
> or
>
> `sudo port install py37-numpy +gcc8`
>
> fixed the problem, but it would be ideal to figure out why exactly before blindly changing the default.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works like a charm for me producing the following output (`Version:3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)`. By the way, you don't need your additional function `make_poly` to create a polynomial. `NumPy` already offers you `poly1d`. The following shortened code without `make_poly` works the same way:

```
fit_result = np.polyfit(xx, yy, 2)
fit_eq = np.poly1d(fit_result)
newX = np.linspace(1420, 1460, 100)
plt.scatter(xx, yy)
plt.plot(newX, fit_eq(newX), 'g', linewidth =.5)
```

[image]

Comment: copy/pasting this gave me an error:
    ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: the entire message:

fit_eq = numpy.poly1d(fit_result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 1090, in __init__
    c_or_r = trim_zeros(c_or_r, trim='f')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1484, in trim_zeros
    if i != 0.:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: What version of NumPy do you have?

Comment: Prior to posting the question 1.15.0 and after upgrade 1.15.1

Comment: Using `poly1d` worked after changing `fit_eq` to `fit_eq[0]`